# VSCode Python Extension: Autocomplete doesn't detect the type of an hinted attribute when it's used in the same method

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-python

When an attribute is created and hinted, and then used in the same method, the autocomplete doesn't work (only shows python object stuff):

[image]

But if I try to use the attribute inside another method, the autocomplete works and show all the specific class stuff:

[image]

Comment: This is weird behavior, happens for me as well, but is probably as designed. If you think this should be changed you could submit a but report for PyLance (Help -> Show all Commands -> Type "Pylance: Report issue...")

Comment: Looks like this only happens for attributes of `self`, maybe because PyLance is expecting them all to be declared in `__init__`?

Comment: While inside the same method, Pylance can actually see that the variable is `None` because you set it in the last line so it ignores the type hint. Inside a different method, Pylance can no longer count on the variable being `None` so it goes with the type hint and treats it as a ndarray.

Comment: Why do you think it has the methods belong to `ndarray` when you define it as **None** in the same method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While inside the same method, Pylance can actually see that the variable is `None` because you set it in the last line so it ignores the type hint. Inside a different method, Pylance can no longer count on the variable being `None` so it goes with the type hint and treats it as a ndarray.

However, if you define it as a proper ndarray in the function, Pylance will autofill correctly as you can see here
[image: in this screenshot]